# Interpretation and use of the correlation matrix and Python and/or Matlab available codes for errors calculations

Tags: regression, python, matlab, scipy

I am writing here because I would like you to help me understanding how to interpret and correctly use the correlation matrix.

From the book of Taylor, "Introduction to error analysis" I can easily understand that in a regression of a set of experimental values $x_i$ and $y_i$ ($i = 1, \dots N$) with a linear function $y = a_1 + a_2x$, the estimation of the errors in the calculated parameters $a_1$ and $a_2$ can be obtained from the propagation of the errors of independent variables and the results are

\begin{eqnarray}%\label{eq:sigma_a1}
\sigma_{a_1} & = & \sigma_y\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{N}x_i^2}{\Delta}}\\
\sigma_{a_2} & = & \sigma_y\sqrt{\frac{N}{\Delta}}
\end{eqnarray}

Where 
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta &=& N\sum_{i = 1}^Nx^2 - \left( \sum_{i = 1}^Nx\right)^2
\end{eqnarray}

and $\sigma_y$ is the variance of the $y_i$ data.

In these formula there is no mention of the covariance $\sigma_{a_1a_2}$, hence it supposes that there is no correlation between $a_1$ and $a_2$. He introduces the concept of covariance later on in the following chapter when he talk about propagation of errors **(1)** and linear correlation **(2)**.

**(1) Covariance in propagation of errors**

When $z = f(x, y)$ is a function of two **independent** normally distributed variables $x$ and $y$ respectively, the error on $z$ is

$$
\sigma_z = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sigma_x \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sigma_y \right)^2 }
$$

And it is the general formula from which the previous expressions $\sigma_{a_1}$ and $\sigma_{a_2}$ can be demonstrated. As I understand this formula is the best estimation of errors only when there is **no correlation** between $x$ and $y$, otherwise (in the case a correlation is present) it is an **overestimation** of the errors.

When $x$ and $y$ are **not independent** than the covariance $\sigma_{x, y}$ is necessary in order to better estimate the error in $z$

$$
\sigma_z = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\sigma_x \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \sigma_y \right)^2 + 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sigma_{x, y}}
$$

**--**

I believe that from this expression a better estimation of the errors $\sigma_{a_1}$ and $\sigma_{a_2}$ can be done. Is that right?

**--**

Moreover inside this root square you can clearly see the presence of the (2x2) correlation matrix, and I have the feeling that it is multiplied (and later on squared) with something like the **Jacobian** matrix, is that right? In other words I have the feeling that a more general formula exists for the estimation of errors with covariance, would you suggest me a webpage in which I can find it, please?

**(2) Covariance in correlation function**

The covariance is later used in the **linear correlation** $r$

$$
r = \frac{\sigma_{x,y}}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} 
$$

and he greatly explain that it can be used in order to figure out whether $x_i$ and $y_i$ are in a linear relationship ( $r \approx\pm 1$ ) or not ( $r \approx 0$ ).

I would like to better understand how to use and interpret the elements $\sigma_{ij}$ of the **covariance matrix** in the more general case in which the regression is not linear.

When the regression is not linear anymore, the estimation of the parameters $a_i$ with $ i = 1 \dots n$ is obtained via the **Levenberg Marquardt Algorithm**. This algorithm is implemented in many software such as Matplab and Python, in which the command is "**curve_fit**". Despite its internal complexity, the use of "curve_fit" looks easy and reliable.

The curve_fit output provides not only an estimation of the parameters $a_i$ and their error $\sigma_{a_i}$. More precisely, its has two output: "**popt**" that is the vector of all the estimated values of the parameters $a_i$  and "**pcov**" that is a symmetrical matrix that is known as the **covariance matrix** with all the variances $\sigma_{a_i}$ in the main diagonal and covariances $\sigma_{a_{ij}}$ as out od diagonal terms.

Now there are other **questions** that I am going to write in the following part of this post:

**1)**

How can I figure out the estimated errors on the parameters $a_i$ from the covariance matrix? I would say that an extension of the previous formula could be

$$
\sigma_z = \sqrt{ \sum_{i, j = 1}^{N}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\sigma_{x_i, x_j}}
$$

I didn't read this formula on any book, its just a supposition I am doing here; is that right?

**(2)**

As I know that in the Levenberg-Marquadt Algorithm I should have to provide the intervals in which the parameters $a_i$ are supposed to be, is there any possible technique that "understand" the best interval from the correlation matrix?

**(3)**

Is there an implemented function in Python and/or Matlab that figure out the errors from the previous formula containing the correlation matrix?

**(4)**

Is there any extension of the concept of linear correlation $r$ to non linear cases?

**(5)**

Could you suggest me any nice book or website that explain to me all these things?

**(6)**

As the formula for the for the error without covariance provides at least an overstimation of the errors, I would say that the covariance terms should be always negative, but this is not clear from the formula itself, what type of consideration is necessary in order to understand the proper sign of those terms in the correlation expression?